# R gplots: Heatmap with side colours

Tags: r, heatmap, gplots

I want to create a heatmap using the `heatmap.2` function from the `gplots` package. This is a minimal example.

```
require(gplots)

# create symmetric matrix
x = matrix(rnorm(100), nrow=10)
diag(x)         <- 1
x[upper.tri(x)] <-  t(x)[upper.tri(x)]
colnames(x)     <- rownames(x) <- letters[1:nrow(x)]

# create side colours
varcols = setNames(rainbow(nrow(x)), rownames(x))

# create heatmap
heatmap.2(x,
          symm = TRUE,             
          trace = "none",          
          revC=TRUE, # <-- THIS IS THE PROBLEM
          ColSideColors = varcols,
          RowSideColors = varcols
          )
```

The problem are the sidecolors. `x` is a symmetric matrix, thus columns and rows should have the same sidecolors. This is fine as long as `revC = FALSE`. However, when I use `revC = TRUE` the order of the colors is messed up. Sometimes - in small examples - it helps to reverse the `ColSideColors`, but that doesn't always work.

Am I doing anything wrong or is this a `gplots` bug?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else who comes across this problem this is how I solved it:

```html
thing = heatmap.2(my_matrix,...RowSideColors=row_cols, revC=F)
ordinary_order = thing$rowInd
reversal = cbind(ordinary_order, rev(ordinary_order))
rev_col = row_cols[reversal[,2]]; rev_col = rev_col[order(reversal[,1])];

heatmap.2(my_matrix, RowSideColors=rev_col, revC=T)
```